# Papyrus restore diagram

Tags: eclipse, git, papyrus

In a eclipse Project I created a Papyrus UML Class Diagram. Papyrus created three files for me, with the endings *.di, *.notation, and *.uml. Now, I committed the project (without eclipse .project file) to a git repository, and fetched it on another machine.

On that machine, everything works fine, except for the papyrus diagram, which I cannot open. Instead, Eclipse shows me simply a grey view. How can I make Eclipse recognize the diagram again?

Addon: Later, I resetted my git working directory (i.e. I threw away my local changes and went back to the last commited state). Now, even on the first machine, I cannot see my diagram anymore...

Comment: Can you please accept any of the answers if anything is worked for you? Because it will help others

Comment: The question is so long ago that I am currently not using Papyrus anymore. So I had no chance yet to try the answers, sorry. Will do so, soon

Answer (score 4):

Found another work around as previous workaround did not work for me.
work around is as follows

1. Open the .di file in Project explorer. It will open di file with grayed editor.
2. Open Papyrus perspective
3. In the Model Explorer view expand your model until you see "Diagram(your class diagram name)". Double click on that.
4. It will open the diagram correctly in the editor now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately just the UML (*.uml) diagram (*.di) and notation (*.notation) files are not currently sufficient to let your local eclipse workspace .metadata "know" its a diagram.

But if on your second machine you:

1.) Save off your existing diagram .di file
2.) Select the *.uml file
3.) Right Click->New->Other->Papyrus (wizard pops up)
4.) Select Papyrus Model
5.) Allow the default diagram name
6.) UML
7.) Class Diagram (e.g.)
8.) Finish

It will create a new diagram and NOT create a new model. Then you can easily copy the old renamed diagram over the top of the new one. 
Papyrus should be happy. Its a workaround, I imagine this is a common problem that will get fixed eventually.